# How to crop jpeg image by 8 lines from 4928x3264 to 4920x3264 (16.1mp to 16mp) without loosing any quality?

Tags: image, crop

How to cut those 8 lines without recompressing the rest of the image?

I want to upload my pictures with original size to google photos but 16.1mp counts against my quota, 16mp doesn't count against my quota. I want to have e.g. 7.1Mb file size preserved, not compressed to 1Mb on google photos.

Comment: can you just save in photoshop or preview on mac as a .jpg with 100% or full image quality settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are obviously looking for a way to **apply lossless transforms to a JPEG file**. In your specific case, a lossless cropping operation is required.

Since the JPEG compression algorithm works on 8x8 pixels blocks (in most cases), one has good reason to think that removing some "lines" of blocks should lead to a valid cropped JPEG file with preserved quality **and** compression ratio.

A cross-platform command-line program called **jpegtran** is dedicated to applying such lossless transforms. It is available here: http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/

Reading the linux manual is a good start: https://linux.die.net/man/1/jpegtran

And here is an exemple of the command to use in your case:

```
jpegtran -crop WxH+X+Y input.jpg > output.jpg
```

`W`: width in pixels, `H`: height in pixels, `X,Y`: starting point position in pixels